# Ending a loop without going back to the start (Python)

Tags: python, loops, user-input

I am trying to create a continuous user input but do not want it to restart from the start if a wrong info is put in. For e.g.,

```
a = 1
while a ==1:
    Number = raw_input("Number: ")
    if len(Number) != 3:
        print "\n Error, please enter 4 digits \n"
    else:    
        Day = raw_input("Day: ")
        if not Day.isdigit():
            print "\n Error, please enter day in digits \n"
```

Here, if the person enters a non-4 digit for the first input, the loop will end and go back to the start again. However, if he gets to the second input and enters a non-digit string, the loop will also end and go back to the start. How do I get it to not go back to the start but ask for the Day again?

Comment: The condition of the loop `a==1` never becomes false because `a` never changes. If you want to end the loop, change `a`.

Comment: The whole point of a loop is that it goes back to the start, that's why it's a loop.. perhaps you don't need a loop? Please clarify your question

Comment: I do not want to end the loop as I want the user to continue entering data and I have an option for the user to end the loop manually. 

Perhaps I should not use a loop and that is my question: any other options to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this by function:

```
def input_number(prompt, digits_num=0):
    while 1:
        s = raw_input(prompt)

        if not s.isdigit():
            print "\n Error, please input digits \n"
            continue

        if digits_num:
            if len(s) != digits_num:
                print "\n Error, please enter %d digits \n" % digits_num
                continue

        result = int(s)
        break

    return result


number = input_number("Number: ", 4)
day = input_number("Day: ")

print "\n number=%d, day=%d" % (number, day)
```

Comment: This works great. And I can use it for other user inputs. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
def myMethod():
    a = 1
    while True:
        if a is 1 and len(raw_input("NUMBER: ")) is not 3:
            print "ERROR IS HERE IN NUMBER"
        else:
            a = 2
            if a is not 1 and raw_input("DAY: ").isdigit() is True:
                a = 1
            else:
                print "ERROR IS HERE IN DAY"
myMethod()
```

you can use this for your purpose. key thing is you need to maintain a key for checking if there is error in DAY or in NUMBER.

Please let me know if you need any other clarification.
this will ask you DAY: and NUMBER: infinitely

Answer (score 1):

You need two separate `while` loops for that purpose. One for `number` and the other one for `day`. Here is the corrected code:

```
number = ""
day = ""

while True:
    number = raw_input("Number: ")
    if not number.isdigit() or len(number) != 4:
        print "Error, Please enter a 4 digit number \n"
    else:
        break


while True:
    day = raw_input("Day: ")
    if not day.isdigit():
        print "\n Error, please enter day in digits \n"
    else:
        break

print "Number: ", number
print "Day: ", day
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Python 3, Use Enum in such scenarios for a production level code. You can always manipulate the conditions according to your needs. Here we go :

```
from enum import Enum

class Status(Enum):
    START = 1
    ‎MIDDLE = 2
    ‎END = 3

state = Status.START

while state != Status.END:
    while state == Status.START:
    ‎    Number = input("Number:")
    ‎    if len(Number) != 3:
    ‎        print("Invalid Number !")
    ‎    else:
    ‎        state = Status.MIDDLE

    while state == Status.MIDDLE:
    ‎    Day = input("Day:")
    ‎    if not Day.isdigit():
    ‎        print("Invaid Day !")
    ‎    else:
    ‎        state = Status.END 
    ‎
```

Answer (score -3):

*Raise Exception until valid input*

```
a = 1
while a ==1:
    try:
        Number = input("Number: ")
        if len(Number) != 3:
            print("\n Error, please enter 4 digits \n")
            raise RuntimeError()
    except RuntimeError:
        continue
    break
```

Comment: Please format your code appropriately and do not use exceptions where a simple assignment can do the job.

Comment: replace the `raise RuntimeError()` with `continue` ... get rid of the try/except